# LDAP authentification with Devise, Rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I am trying to login using LDAP and Devise, but it does not work for some reason.

In my LDAP file I only have:

```
host: xxxxxxxx
port: 389
attribute: uid
base: ou=Students, dc=xxx, dc=xx, dc=xx
ssl: false
```

My model is called User though.

Is it normal for the query that Devise makes on its own to be ... ?

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'xxxx' LIMIT 1
```

I really couldn't find documentation on this. Could you please help?

Comment: How do you find out about what the values are for "attribute" and "base" ?

Comment: Sorry, @garbagecollection, I don't really understand your question. If you are trying to help, you are a bit too late, my solution is below. If you are asking because you need a solution for one of your problems, I might not be the person to ask. :)

Comment: No I need help :( So I'm wondering about `attribute: uid` and `base: ou=Students, dc=xxx, dc=xx, dc=xx`. Did you have to ask your sys admin or someone like that for this info?

Comment: @garbagecollection, yes! They have been provided to me by the ones that are handling the LDAP thing. I assume you have to do the same if you are trying something like this, I am not aware of any way of finding them out on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone as confused about LDAP as I am, the answer is: **yes, it is normal**.

Maybe I should have mentioned that I was talking about the [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable) gem in my original question. My bad.

In the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file you will find the configuration file for `devise` and `devise_ldap_authenticatable`, where there will be a line sort of like:

```
config.ldap_create_user = false (by default)
```

If this is changed to true, then it will create a user in the local database whenever a successful login has occurred. This is why the SQL statement in the first post exists, it is just looking to see if the user is already saved. The odd thing about it is that it executes and displays the statement even if the `ldap_create_user` option is false.